# Build Error Asp.Net MVC 3 Entity Framework auto generated file

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

Please help me. I am new to that domain.

I have created an ASP.NET MVC 3 project using Visual Studio 2012, SQL Server 2008 R2 & .NET Framework 4.5. I wanted to create an Entity Framework auto-generated model class file (`.edmx`) from an existing database. After generation the auto-generated `,edmx` file whenever I build the project it's showing me below errors. Please help me how to fix that issue.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed issue by deleting the existing `edmx` class file and re-creating the auto-generated file again by giving the different name of ado.net entity data model class. I have also deleted `.tt` file inside the `edmx` file as well. thank you.